# Can't access VisualSVN repository via HTTPS

Tags: windows-7, visualsvn-server

I have VisualSVN Server running on Windows 7 64-bit. The repository is located in C:\Repositories. When I try to access it over HTTPS, I get the following error:

> Could not open the requested SVN filesystem, error code 500 # 720005.

I've tried giving the admin user full rights to the repository directory, but that doesn't work. The only way I can get access over HTTPS is if I give everyone full rights, which is obviously unsafe.

How can I grant access to the repository only to specific users?

I have also tried freeing the respective directories with full access to the user "Netzwerkdienst" (= network service) which doesn't work too. Just freeing the directories for the user "Jeder" (=Everyone) works.

Enclosed the Event-Logger entry: Protokollname: VisualSVNServer Quelle: VisualSVN Server 2.5 Datum: 22.02.2013 08:57:24 Ereignis-ID: 1003 Aufgabenkategorie:(2) Ebene: Fehler Schlüsselwörter:Klassisch Benutzer: Nicht zutreffend Computer: TZEModbusLogger Beschreibung:

Could not open password file: C:/Repositories/htpasswd (OS 5) Zugriff verweigert [client fe80::8136:f1b6:6e71:cb91] Ereignis-XML: ;   1003 2 2 0x80000000000000

454 VisualSVNServer TZEModbusLogger    Could not open password file: C:/Repositories/htpasswd  (OS 5) Zugriff verweigert  fe80::8136:f1b6:6e71:cb91

Comment: VisualSVN likely runs as the `LOCAL SERVICE` system account, have you tried giving that access?

Comment: Nope! VisualSVN Server service runs under 'Network Service' account by default.

Comment: Check server log. What events get generated there? See http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00028/

Comment: I have also tried freeing the respective directories with full access to the user "Netzwerkdienst" (= network service) which doesn't work too. Just freeing the directories for the user "Jeder" (=Everyone) works. Enclosed the Event-Logger entry: Protokollname: VisualSVNServer
Quelle:        VisualSVN Server 2.5
Datum:         22.02.2013 08:57:24
Ereignis-ID:   1003
Aufgabenkategorie:(2)
Ebene:         Fehler
Schlüsselwörter:Klassisch
Benutzer:      Nicht zutreffend
Computer:      TZEModbusLogger
Beschreibung:

Comment: Could not open password file: C:/Repositories/htpasswd
(OS 5) Zugriff verweigert  [client fe80::8136:f1b6:6e71:cb91]
Ereignis-XML:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="VisualSVN Server 2.5" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1003</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>2</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-02-22T07:57:24.000000000Z" />

Comment: <EventRecordID>454</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>VisualSVNServer</Channel>
    <Computer>TZEModbusLogger</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Could not open password file: C:/Repositories/htpasswd
</Data>
    <Data>(OS 5) Zugriff verweigert  </Data>
    <Data>fe80::8136:f1b6:6e71:cb91</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>